# Adding external source in /etc/hosts linux

Tags: localhost, ubuntu-14.04, virtual-hosts

As we know that we could actually add external source file from our `~/.bashrc` file. For example I have a list of my custom aliases to be included inside it. To do it I simply add inside the file:

> source /path/to/my/external/file

or I could simply replace 'source' with dot (.) like so:

> . /path/to/my/external/file

Then I can access all my custom aliases without manually typing it inside the ~/.bashrc file.

My question is:

I was wondering is there a similar way to include external source file inside `/etc/hosts` file? I've tried the same method above, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks and CMIIW.

Comment: Um, [DNS](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to include external source file/s inside `/etc/hosts` unlike how it's done with `~/.bashrc` or any other systems on Linux.